# connect to WCF net.tcp protocol from Python

Tags: python, wcf

I am using a SOAP API using the library **suds** but not sure if I can just use a Python library for this problem.

Firstly, I connect to the API.

```
client.Client("http://localhost:8003/mex")
```

Once I am connected, can see every method in the API but the problem is when I try to call one:

```
client.service.MethodX()
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: net.tcp>
```

I have spoken with the provider and at runtime, the API is exposed at net.tcp://localhost:8002/PublicAPI. I don't manage to find a solution about this problem without creating a bridge developed in C# to send the data to my Python script.

Comment: can you ask the provider to enable an http binding? it will simply be a config change for the provider

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if the service is exposed using `NetTcpBinding` there is no way for you to consume it using a SOAP-based library because `net.tcp` uses binary message encoding (message is not transported in SOAP format). Furthermore (AFAIK) WCF's `net.tcp` is not conforming to any industry-wide standards and is designed for high performance communication between .NET apps, not for interoperability. In light of that, i doubt you'll be able to consume the service directly from Python in any way. Possible options in that case are:

1. Create a .NET bridge and consume that from Python (as you've mentioned)
2. Ask the service provider to expose an additional endpoint with ie. basicHttpBinding